# localhost/phppgmyadmin displaying error 403

Tags: postgresql, xampp, http-status-code-403, phppgadmin

I want to integrate postgresql in xampp and when i am trying to open in my web browser "localhost/phppgmyadmin" Error number 403 Forbideen is displayed please help!

I followed the steps in an online video but it dosent work the below is my httpd-xampp.config file contents  :

Comment: Can not see your httpd-xampp.conf file. Is it the only file you have edited?